# Rotate cylinder using AxisAngle4d in Java3D

Tags: java, vector, rotation

I'm currently trying to rotate a cylinder so it will align with a given vector (therefore "drawing" the vector). Additionally this should update after a specific time and the vector should be drawn again accordingly to the changed vector.
I am using AxisAngle4d to rotate the cylinder about the origin. The rotation parameters are calculated using the cross product for the axis and the angle between the 2 vectors as angle...

Here is the basic code:

```
//Returns rotation axis and rotation angle
public AxisAngle4d getRotation(Vector3d start, Vector3d target)
{
    //Get rotation axis
    Vector3d cross=new Vector3d();
    // TODO: Catch small angles (ignore cross product)
    cross.cross(start,target);

    //Get rotation angle between start and target
    double angle=start.angle(target);

    //Create AxisAngle4f with rotation axis and angle parameters
    AxisAngle4d rot = new AxisAngle4d(cross,angle);

    //Test
    System.out.println("Rot: "+rot);

    //return rotation parameters
    return rot;
}

//Rotates arrow to target vector
public void rotate(TransformGroup object,Vector3d startVector,Vector3d targetVector)
{
    //TODO: Always reset rotation to 0? 
    //new Transform3D containing rotation information
    Transform3D rotator = new Transform3D();
    //Set rotation so it will rotate to targetVector
    rotator.setRotation(getRotation(startVector,targetVector));
    //get previous rotation and copy into temp 
    Transform3D temp3d = new Transform3D();
    object.getTransform(temp3d);
    //combine two rotations
    temp3d.mul(rotator);
    //Set Transform to new rotation
    object.setTransform(temp3d);

}

//perform Rotations after update
public void updateRotation()
{
    //call rotator for each arrow
    rotate(axisArrowX,this.temp_satOrientationX,this.satOrientationX);
    rotate(axisArrowY,this.temp_satOrientationY,this.satOrientationY);
    rotate(axisArrowZ,this.temp_satOrientationZ,this.satOrientationZ);
}
```

The Problem is that the cylinders won't rotate the right way. I checked the AxisAngle4d and it seems correct, but the performed rotation doesn't correspond.

Any Ideas whats wrong? (especially in the rotate method)

Thanks, Tom